# SendGrid API sends email locally but it doesn’t work after publishing the MVC app on the Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, sendgrid-api-v3

I have used the tutorial of Microsoft(see by clicking the link below) to implement the system of sending account verification email and password resetting email using SendGrid.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-2.2&github-auth-complete=true#feedback

My code and everything is the same as shown in the tutorial and It works when I run my .net core app locally, it also sends emails using SendGrid. But after publishing it on the azure it suddenly stopped sending emails. Can’t understand what’s the issue. If anyone comes up with the solution, please help me solve the problem.

Thank you.

My Code: 
EmailSender.cs

```
 public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; } //set only via Secret Manager

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
    }

    public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
    {
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress("garycleaners@gmail.com", "EnvirosafeWebApp"),
            Subject = subject,
            PlainTextContent = message,
            HtmlContent = message
        };
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

        // Disable click tracking.
        // See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html
        msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);

        return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

AuthMessageSenderOptions.cs

```
  public class AuthMessageSenderOptions
{
    public string SendGridKey { get; set; }
}
```

In the tutorial, they have told to use SendGridUser, but it is not required.

Secrets.json

```
{"SendGridKey": "MyAPIKey"}
```

Comment: You need to include the relevant code here, directly in the question. Please see [MCVE] so you get an idea of what code to include.

Comment: I have added .cs files and SendGrid user secrets from services that actually connect my application with SendGrid.

Comment: It seems fishy that you put the from address as a Gmail address. I have not used SendGrid, but i wouldn't expect the receiving server to be happy that the from address is from a gmail account when it clearly isn't. There is a response back from the server that youre not capturing. Try awaiting your asyncronous email, store the response in a variable, and then inspect its properties.

Comment: Using gmail address or any other true address works locally, basically what's happening here is sendgrid uses the email address mentioned in from address to send email. If that's a dummy address, sendgrid won't send any email.

Comment: Did you try as I suggested? Capture the response from your API call? What was the result?

Comment: Did you verify that the Secrets.json file is being deployed to Azure with the rest of the website?

Comment: @mason, I didn't try that you told me. I found that secrets.json is saved on my OS and isn't deployed on azure for security reasons, As DBro commented. So the solution for this problem is to put everything in secrets.json on the azure portal(in your Application Settings) manually, in my case it is APIKey. It worked for me. Thanks for your help and taking interest in my question.